# Mixing Stain/sealers

Tags: deck, staining, sealer

I am trying to match a new deck color to an existing deck that was stained with Olympic Maximum stain and sealant in the “natural tone cedar” color. I purchased the wood rx product in the cedar color hoping that they would match pretty closely. They do not. Can I mix the Olympic Maximum with the wood rx to try to match the colors closer? I believe both are water-based. I have probably just enough of both left to finish the new deck.

[image]

The deck to the right is 2 years old. Stained with the Olympic Maximum 2 years ago. I recently pressure washed it and then applied one coat of the Wood rx.

The left deck is new. It has one coat of wood rx on it.

Comment: There are no photos in your post for us to see what you're talking about.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I guess the file size was too large so it didn’t upload the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *try* - likely there will be noticeable difference of new to old until 2 years difference is an insignificant part of their time in service.

It's hard to predict how mixing the two products will go, even if both are waterbased. Try mixing only a small amount as a test.